# Show jquery dialog once per user

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I use modal dialog on page open and I'd like to show it once for each user.
Here is the code,but it doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true
    }); 
    $(function() {
        if ($.cookie('shownDialog') != 'true') {
            $('#dialog').dialog();
        }
        $.cookie('shownDialog', 'true', {expires: 7});
    });
    $("#close").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(":ui-dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

**Can someone help me to fix code?**

Comment: You ought to be more specific than 'it doesn't work'. How doesn't it work? What do you expect it to and what do you actually see? Errors? Stack traces? Better questions == better, quicker answers (usually).

Comment: Posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is also usually a good idea; for JS problems, consider using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to post working examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're seeing the dialog always instead of once per user.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true
});
```

This part is going to show the dialog immediately, before ever reaching your check for display.

You should get rid of it and move your modal option into the if block instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
          if ($.cookie('shownDialog') != 'true') {
              $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true
               }); 
          }
          $.cookie('shownDialog', 'true', {expires: 7});
    });
    $("#close").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest(":ui-dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code in Jsbin,but I can't display the modal dialog.This is source code [link] http://jsbin.com/axeru4/edit

Comment: The example you've linked to doesn't have the cookie plugin included so it won't run - see the JavaScript console/Firebug and you'll see the error.